# How do I write two equations next to each other and reference them?

Tags: tables, equations, overleaf

One describes a phenomenon for oxygen and the other for hydrogen:

[image]

I write these side by side with the code:

```
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
            $\frac{\text{d}\delta^{2}\text{H}}{\text{dT}}+ 3\permil/^{\circ} \text{C}\approx1.5 \permil/100\; \text{m}\;\; $ &$\;\;\frac{\text{d}\delta^{18}\text{O}}{\text{dT}}+ 0.4\permil/^{\circ} \text{C}\approx-0.2 \permil/100\; \text{m} $
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

However, I want there to be a number on the right side so that I can reference these equations: it should look like this:
[image]

What should I do?

ps. I always consider the two calculations together, so I only have to refence them once

Comment: A single number for two equations??

Comment: Yes I always consider the two calculations simultaneously, so yes, one number is enough for both.

Comment: So i modified my question :-)

Comment: In this  case, write both formulæ in an equation environment, and add some spacing in-between (e.g. add `\qquad`).

Comment: thanks can you write this as a Answer, so I can accept this :-) cause it works perfectly and is a easy solution I didn´t even think about it! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: and it even looks so much cleaner

Comment: Thank you for your kind appreciation. It will be done in a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it (not knowing which packages you load):

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{esdiff}
    \usepackage{wasysym}
    \usepackage{upgreek}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
    \diff{\updelta^{2}\mathrm{H}}{\mathrm{T}} + 3\permil/\unit{\degreeCelsius} \approx 1.5\permil/ \qty{100}{m}\hspace{4em}
    \diff{\updelta^{18}\mathrm{O}}{\mathrm{T}} + 0.4\permil/\unit{\degreeCelsius} \approx -0.2\permil / \qty{100}{m}
    \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image]